# ASP.NET - Remove Header/Sorting row when exporting datatable to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable, export-to-excel

Help me please.

I would like to know how to export  my datatable to excel worksheet without header or sorting row (Which is the 1st row).

Here's my code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bscConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();



            cmd.CommandText = "FechasRango1";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha2", TextBox2.Text);


            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('No Hay Resultados');</script>");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.xlsx");
                MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's my result:
[image]

Comment: What is XLWorkbook ? What are your usings?

Comment: using ClosedXML.Excel;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;
using OfficeOpenXml.FormulaParsing.Excel.Functions.Logical;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using CSOpenXmlExportImportExcel;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this line of code you have gives you the worksheet you just added in return:

> wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

Save that in a variable, lets sheet and delete the first row:

```
sheet.Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.Delete();
```

Looks like you are using ClosedXML library. [Here](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Inserting%20and%20Deleting%20Rows&referringTitle=Documentation) you will find many examples of how to delete the row.

Comment: The folowing error comes up: " Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'IXLRange' does not contain a definition for 'EntireRow' and no extension method 'EntireRow' accepting a first argument of type 'IXLRange' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? "

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ClosedXML;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
`